# I am coding in python2. I need to create a function called change() that changes the value of a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

The function should accept three pieces of information: a value, given as a string, and a row and an index, which I need to be given as a tuple. The dictionary is an asymmetrical game board. The purpose of change() function is to change the value of the strings contained in the lists stored in the keys of the dictionary when given an "position" (row as a string and column as an index/integer, maybe combined as tuple), changes the "value" at that index. Here is my code:

```
board = dict()
board['a'] = ['t']
board['b'] = ['0','t','0','0','t','0']
board['c'] = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
board['d'] = ['0','0','0','0','0','0']
board['e'] = ['0','0','0','0']


print board['a'][0]

def change(value,position):
    board[position()]=value

change('G',('c', 4))

print board['c'][3]
```

I think I get how I should call it, but I can't figure out how to make the function change(). I get the error "Type Error: 'Tuple' object is not callable". I am a beginner, so I really appreciate any help. I have tried to research this issue, but I haven't found the answer thus far. Thanks!

Comment: what is `position`? a function , tuple?

Answer (score 3):

```
board[position()]=value
```

Instead try this -

```
board[position[0]][position[1]]=value
```

As well , to print the changed value -

```
print board['c'][4]
```

Comment: Tuples can't be array indices in the standard libraries

Answer (score 0):

Writing `x()` means you are *calling* x. For example `change('G',('c', 4))` means you called the function `change` with the arguments `G` and `('c', 4)`. You can do this because `change` is a function, as shown by the statement `def change...`. Functions are the most common kind of callable object. Tuples are not callable. That is, you cannot call them. You cannot write `x()` if `x` is a tuple. That is what the error is telling you.

Now, where have you done this? In fact the error should be telling you that too, quite explicitly. Not the part of the error that you showed us, but the full thing. You should have seen something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 14, in <module>
    change('G',('c', 4))
  File "t.py", line 12, in change
    board[position()]=value
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

This is a traceback, meaning that it is tracing back through the sequence of calls that led to this error. It tells us the order it's in. That means that the first call in the chain is at the top, and you can read it like a story. You called `change('G',('c', 4))` at line 14 in the program. From the definition `def change(value,position)`, that means `value = 'G'` and more importantly `position = ('c', 4)`, a tuple. That led to `board[position()]=value`. Note the `position()`.